# Trying to understand python multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

Please consider this code:

```
import threading

def printer():
    for i in range(2):
        with lock:
            print ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

def main():
    global lock
    lock = threading.Lock()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=printer) for x in xrange(2)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
        t.join()

main()
```

I can understand this code and it is clear: We create two threads and we run them sequentially - we run second thread only when first thread is finished. Ok, now consider another variant:

```
import threading

def printer():
    for i in range(2):
        with lock:
            print ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

def main():
    global lock
    lock = threading.Lock()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=printer) for x in xrange(2)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

main()
```

What happens here? Ok, we run them in parallel, but what is the purpose of make main thread waiting for child threads in second variant? How it can influence on the output?

Comment: Its goal is to run the all the threads in parallel so multiple jobs are being done at once. Iirc though, if this is run using a CPython implementation, the GIL will prevent this from operating as expected. You might want to clarify your question, because it's not clear what exactly you're asking here.

Comment: Calling `thread.join` waits for the thread to finish executing. So the second case will start both threads running, and then wait for the first thread to finish, and then wait for the second thread to finish. In practice, both threads will run in parallel and it doesn't matter too much which finishes first - the main thread will effectively wait for both to finish (by waiting for one and then the other).

Comment: What is the purpose of main thread waiting for child threads in second variant? How it can influence on the output?

Comment: Is the question "How would the output be different if there were no `join`s in the main thread?"

Comment: Yes,  I cant understand the purpose of join in second variant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second variant, the ordering of execution is much less defined.
The lock is released each time through the loop in printer.  In both variants, you have two threads and two loops within a thread.
In the first variant, since only one thread runs at a time, you know the total ordering.
In the second variant, each time the lock is released, the thread running may change.
So you might get

- thread 1 loop 1
- thread 1 loop 2
- thread 2 loop 1
- thread 2 loop 2

or perhaps
* thread 2 loop 1
* thread 1 loop 1
* thread 1 loop 2
* thread 2 loop 2

The only constraint is that loop1 within a given thread runs before loop 2 within that thread and that the two print statements come together since the lock is held for both of them.

In this particular case I'm not sure the call to `t.join()` in the second variant has an observable effect.  It guarantees that the main thread will be the last thread to end, but I'm not sure that in this code you can observe that in any way.  In more complex code, joining the threads can be important so that cleanup actions are only performed after all threads terminate.  This can also be very important if you have daemon threads, because the entire program will terminate when all non-daemon threads terminate.

Comment: But what is the purpose of calling joins in second variant? How it actually influence on the things happening?

Answer (score 0):

To better understand the multithreading in python, you need to first understand the relationship between the `main` thread and the `children` threads.

The `main` thread is the entry of the program, it is created by your system when you run your script. For example, in your script, the `main` function is run in the `main` thread.

While the `children` thread is created by your `main` thread when you instanate the `Thread` class.

The most important thing is how the main thread controls the children thread. Basically, the instance of the `Thread` is everything that the `main` thread know about and control over this child thread. At the time when a child thread is created, this child thread does not run immediately, until the main thread call `start` function on this thread instance. After the start the child thread, you can assume that the `main` thread and the `child` thread is running parallelly now.

But one more important thing is how the `main` thread knows that the task of `child` thread is done. Though the `main` thread knows nothing about how the task is done by the `child` thread, it does be aware of the running status of the `child` thread. `Thread.is_alive` can check the status of a thread by the `main` thread. In pratice, the `Thread.join` function is always used to tell the `main` thread wait until the `child` thread is done. This function will block the `main` thread.

Okay, let's examine the two script you are confused with. For the first script:

```
for t in threads:
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

The `children` threads in the loop are `start`ed and then `join`ed one by one. Note that `start` does not block `main` thread, while `join` will block the `main` thread wait until this `child` thread is done. Thus they are running sequentially.

While for the second script:

```
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

All `children` threads are started in the first loop. As the `Thread.start` function will not block the `main` thread, all `children` threadings are running parallelly after the first loop. In the second loop, the `main` thread will wait for the task done of each `child` thread one by one.

Now I think you should notice the difference between these two script: in the first one, `children` threads running one by one, while in the second script, they are running simultaneously.

There are other useful topics for the python threading:

(1) How to handle the Keyboard Interrupt Exception, e.g., when I want to terminate the program by `Ctrl-C`? Only the `main` thread will receive the exception, you have to handle the termination of `children` threads.

(2) Multithreading vs Multiprocessing. Although we are saying that threading is parallel, it is not the real parallel in CPU level. So if your application is CPU intensive, try multiprocessing, and if your application is I/O intensive, multithreading maybe sufficient.

By the way, read through the documentation of python threading section and try some code may help you understand it.

Hope this would be helpful. Thanks.